# how to link one iboutlet and two xib files

Tags: xib, iboutlet

How can i use the same IBOutlet variable to be linked to  UILabel in two different xib files but in the same project?

I want to switch these xib files using initWithNib function.
When i try to load the other xib file i am getting an error

setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key  'some ibooutlet variable'.

How can i load the other xib file by using the same IBoutlet variable.Reason for doing so is that i need not have to make much modification in the code.

Answer (score 1):

You can't "switch" by using initWithNib. **Because you already have initialized your viewController with one xib**. What you can, is create a new viewController and initialize it with the second xib.